# Add two data frames together based on matching column names

Tags: r

I have two data sets and I want to add them together based on matching column names. For the data sets, each row represents a study site and each column represents a survey. Each survey is restricted to one block. I want to add the contents of each data set together based on column names.

Data set 1 (1 denotes a survey was performed):

```
Block A1  A2  A3  A4  A5
    1  0   1   0   0   0
    2  1   0   0   1   0
    3  0   0   1   0   1
```

Data set 2 is a subset of data set 1 in which the 1 now represents that the species of interest was found during the survey

Data set 2:

```
Block  A1  A2  A4  A5
    1   0   1   0   0
    3   0   0   0   1
```

The ideal out put would look something like this where 2 represents that a survey was performed and the species of interest was found, 1 represents that a survey was performed and 0 that no surveys were performed.

Data set 3:

```
Block A1  A2  A3  A4  A5
  1    0   2   0   0   0
  2    1   0   0   1   0
  3    0   0   1   0   2
```

Comment: How big is your data?

Comment: I have ~3500 surveys (columns) over 220 sites (rows) for data set 1 and dataset 2 has ~130 surveys over 56 sites.

Comment: And you don't have every column of ever survey?

Comment: Correct, in data set 2 the surveys that didn't contain the species of interest were removed. It was the only way I could get the data out of access.

Comment: You want the addition to be based on column *and row*, right? Is there a typo in the output? Dataset 2, row label 3 has a 1 in column 4, but it looks like that got added to the column 3 row 3 from Dataset 2...

Comment: Yes, there was a typo. I was just created the data to symbolize what I wanted. It should be corrected now. Thank you for pointing that out.

Comment: @divibisan they are similar, but we're dealing with a case here where one dataframe doesn't have all of the columns.

Comment: @gersht `bind_rows` doesn't require both dataframes to have the same columns, so there's no difference there. In fact, your answer to this question is identical to the accepted answer on that duplicate (with the exception of using the `na.rm=T` parameter)

Comment: @divibisan one dataframe above doesn't have all the columns. That's the difference. The OP also explicitly says they want to sum based on matching column names, while the other OP wants to sum duplicate rows. I think they are what Atwood would call [borderline duplicates](https://stackoverflow.blog/2009/04/29/handling-duplicate-questions/): "There’s often benefit to having multiple subtle variants of a question around, as people tend to ask and search using completely different words, and the better our coverage, the better odds our fellow programmers can find the answer they’re looking for."

Comment: @gersht That's fine, people have different opinions on duplicates – that's why we have the moderation and close vote system we have. Still, I think the fact that the code in the answer is identical to that in the duplicate is a pretty good clue that this is, in fact, a duplicate

Comment: @divibisan the "opinion" in this case is SO's preferred approach. It also makes sense: The same problem can be formulated differently, and apparent duplicates can highlight different aspects of the same problem. Still, I don't entirely disagree with you. My last comment was meant to move us past the "duplicate vs. nonduplicate" discussion. It's obvious that they are, at some level, duplicates. But both also add something unique. The data in the other post have, for instance, the same number of columns with the same names, which suggests an approach that doesn't necessitate `bind_rows`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Edit

*You seem a little uncomfortable using dplyr verbs and `%>%`, so I've decided to add a couple other possible solutions that you might find more appealing.*

*Note that none of these solutions will work if one or more of your variables is non-numeric, which seems to be the case for your real data. You'll need to find out which are non-numeric, and either convert them to numeric or drop them.*

### Using base R

The `rbind` function will concatenate dataframes by matching variables if they all have the same variables. You should add missing variables to your dataframes with value `NA`, then `rbind` them. You can then call `aggregate` on a subset of your combined dataframes and sum by the levels of `Block`:

```r
full_df <- rbind(df1, cbind(df2, A3 = NA))
aggregate(full_df[,2:6], list(Block = full_df$Block), sum, na.rm = T)

#### OUTPUT ####

  Block A1 A2 A3 A4 A5
1     1  0  2  0  0  0
2     2  1  0  0  1  0
3     3  0  0  1  0  2
```

### Using dplyr

The dplyr function `bind_rows` is quite flexible, and makes concatenating dataframes a little easier by matching shared variables, and automatically filling unmatched variables with `NA`. Group by `Block` and use `summarise_all` to apply the function to every variable:

```r
library(dplyr)

bind_rows(df1, df2) %>%
    group_by(Block) %>% 
    summarise_all(sum, na.rm = T)

#### OUTPUT ####

# A tibble: 3 x 6
  Block    A1    A2    A3    A4    A5
  <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int>
1     1     0     2     0     0     0
2     2     1     0     0     1     0
3     3     0     0     1     0     2
```

### Using data.table

Another option would be to use data.table, which has a reputation for being fast, as well as a different syntax that some prefer.

```r
library(data.table)

full_df <- rbindlist(list(df1, df2), fill = T)
full_df[, lapply(.SD, sum, na.rm = T), by = "Block"]

#### OUTPUT ####

   Block A1 A2 A3 A4 A5
1:     1  0  2  0  0  0
2:     2  1  0  0  1  0
3:     3  0  0  1  0  2
```

Comment: When I tried running through this code I received                                                      "Error in group_by(Blocks, add = TRUE) : object 'Blocks' not found"

Comment: "this code" doesn't include the argument `add = TRUE`, so it sounds like your trying something else.

Comment: Originally I had deleted the %>% which caused that error. Once I inserted those back in I received the error "Error in sum(rn, na.rm = TRUE) : invalid 'type' (character) of argument"

Comment: @DevinMendez if you change the code and don't show me your changes I can't help you.

Comment: I used the same exact code that you posted above, and received the error        "Error in sum(rn, na.rm = TRUE) : invalid 'type' (character) of argument"

Comment: @DevinMendez it's because column `rn` in your dataframe is type character. Either remove it or convert it into type numeric.

Comment: @DevinMendez I've added a couple more options so you don't have to deal with the `%>%` if you don't want to. However, you will still have to convert your character variable to numeric or drop it.

Comment: I was able to get the dplyr method to work once I transposed my data. Not sure if it worked because there were less columns to deal with? Anyways thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1):

So I would approach this a bit more inefficiently than other people here:

```
library(tidyverse)

data1 %>% 
gather(key,value,-Block) %>% 
rbind(data2 %>% 
gather(key,value, -Block)) %>% 
group_by(Block, key) %>% 
summarise(All_vals = sum(value)) %>% 
spread(key, All_vals)
```

Here is the result:

```
 Block    A1    A2    A3    A4    A5
  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1     1     0     2     0     0     0
2     2     1     0     0     1     0
3     3     0     0     1     1     2
```

Comment: This is nice in that it would work just as well if `data2` has some elements missing from `data1`, not just the other way.

Comment: I am relatively new to R and I don't understand what "%>%" symbolizes.

Comment: @DevinMendez it is the pipe operator and is part of the `tidyverse` language and it means "pass the results from the left hand side of the pipe and pass it to the following." This allows us to process data without necessarily storing intermediate steps.

Comment: @akash87 thank you for explaining that to me. I received the error                                "Error in sum(value) : invalid 'type' (character) of argument"

Comment: Are you posting real data or example data?

Comment: It was example data. All of the data is binary though.

Comment: So print out part of the data after your run the code from `data1` through the first `gather`

Answer (score 0):

Using base R!

```
matrix2 <- matrix(rep(0, length.out = nrow(dataset1)*ncol(dataset1)),
ncol = ncol(dataset1))
#then make sure the column names match dataset1 (not dataset2)
names(matrix2) <- names(dataset1)
for (i in 1:ncol(matrix2)) {
if (any(names(dataset2) == names(matrix2)[i]
matrix2[,i] <- dataset2[,which(names(dataset2) == names(matrix2)[i]]
}
}
```

Then add the these columns, which are in the same position/order as dataset1 (or are zero otherwise), to dataset1:

```
for (i in 1:ncol(dataset1) {dataset1[,i] <- dataset1[,i] + matrix2[,i]}
```